# Comparing floating point numbers in D

Tags: floating-point, d

I am currently implementing Quaternions and I run into the following problem

```d
unittest{
    auto q1 = Quaternion(Vec3f(1, 0, 0), Degrees(90));
    writeln("length ", q1.magnitude);
    assert(q1.magnitude is 1.0f);
}
```

Where it prints `1` but the assert fails, which means the value is very close to `1` but not exactly.

In my vector code I always used the following apporach

```d
/**
      Compares two vectors with a tolerance value, if the type of the vector
      is a floating pointer number.
*/
bool equals(Vec, T = Vec.Type)(const Vec v1, const Vec v2, T tolerance = kindaSmallNumber)
if(isVector!Vec && isFloatingPoint!(Vec.Type)){
    import std.math: abs;
    import breeze.meta: zip;
    import std.algorithm.iteration: map;
    import std.algorithm.searching: all;
    return zip(v1.data[], v2.data[]).map!(t => abs(t[0] - t[1]) < kindaSmallNumber).all;
}
```

Where I basically do `abs( a - b ) < tolerance`.

I could generalize this to something like this

```d
bool equalsf(float a, float b, float tolerance = 0.00001){
    import std.math: abs;
    return abs( a - b ) < tolerance;
}
```

and then I could rewrite

```d
unittest{
    auto q1 = Quaternion(Vec3f(1, 0, 0), Degrees(90));
    assert(q1.magnitude.equalsf(1.0f));
}
```

But now I am wondering if there is already a standard way of comparing floating point numbers in D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [approxEqual](http://dlang.org/library/std/math/approx_equal.html) function from standard library

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [gfm](https://github.com/d-gamedev-team/gfm/tree/master/math/gfm/math),[gl3n](http://dav1dde.github.io/gl3n/), or [m3d](https://github.com/AmberThrall/m3d) they all provide a vector and quaternion type.

Comment: This answers which part of the question exactly?

Comment: it answers the meta question. that the author should not reinvent the wheel. additionally there has been a talk about floating point math and especially comparison at this year's DConf. Long story short, do not compare floats equality.